# Add same hard coded object to NSDictionary for the count of an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array that has 5 object in. like so:

```
  NSMutableArray *categoriesMutableNameArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[prefs arrayForKey:@"categoriesImageUrl"]];
```

I get the array values from a web service and the array looks like: fashion, Mens, Ladies, Gadgets.

I then save the array to a dictionary like so:

```
  NSDictionary = @{ @"title" : categoriesMutableNameArray, @"selected": @"No"};
```

You will notice that I have a hard coded field in the dictionary called "selected": @"No".

How can I make another array with selected so that the selected array equals that to the count of categoriesMutableNameArray so for each entry in categoriesMutableNameArray I want to make a selected object. I basically want the following:

```
NSArray *select = [arraWithObjects:@"No"];
```

but I want to add @"No" to the select array to be the same as the count for categoriesMutableNameArray.

So if there are 4 objects in categoriesMutableNameArray like so:

fashion, Mens, Ladies, Gadgets.  I would like NSArray *select to have the same amount of objects categoriesMutableNameArray has like so :

```
NSArray *select  =[arraWithObjects:@"No",@"No",@"No",@"No"];
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 NSMutableArray *categoriesMutableNameArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[prefs arrayForKey:@"categoriesImageUrl"]];
 NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 for (id element in categoriesMutableNameArray) {
     [array addObject:@"No"];
 }

 NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"title" : categoriesMutableNameArray, @"selected": array};
```

Answer (score 0):

hm...

```
NSMutableArray *select = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int count = 0; count < [categoriesMutableNameArray count]; count++) {
   [select addObject:@"No"];
}
```